# Spring Boot: Adding @Transcational to a test makes the test fail, otherwise it passes

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I am trying to test an update query in a CrudRepository

```
@Repository
public interface AutomationInformationRepository extends 
CrudRepository<AutomationInformation, Long> {
List<AutomationInformation> findByControlID (String controlID);
List<AutomationInformation> findByCsmpAutomationState(CSMPAutomation csmpAutomation);

AutomationInformation findFirstByControlID (String controlID);

 //    AutomationInformation findOne(Long aId);

AutomationInformation findByAID(Long aId);
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("update AutomationInformation a set a.csmpAutomationState = ?1 where a.aID = ?2")
int  setCsmpAutomationState(CSMPAutomation active,long aId);
 }
```

I am running a test where I get a entry from the database, update it and then retrieve it again and check that the value has been updated correctly.

When I add @Transactional to the test to roll it back after the test runs, the test fails with the update not taking place in the object I retrieve. However when I take out @Transactional it passes and I can see the update has taken place in the DB

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest
public class AutomationInformationRepoTest {

@Autowired
AutomationInformationRepository repo;

@Test
public void testSetAutomationInformationActiveByAID() {
    //this control csmpatomation is set to NOAUTO
    //insert a dummy automationInformation

AutomationInformation auto = repo.findByAID((long) 588);
//CONFIRM IT IS SET TO NOAUTO
assertEquals(auto.getCsmpAutomation(),CSMPAutomation.NOAUTO);
// set it to active
int result =repo.setCsmpAutomationState(CSMPAutomation.ACTIVE, 
auto.getaID());
//confirm 1 row was changed
assertEquals(result,1);

 //retrieve it again, it should be active now
AutomationInformation auto2 = repo.findByAID((long) 588);

assertEquals(auto2.getCsmpAutomation(),CSMPAutomation.ACTIVE);
}
}
```

Comment: Which Transactional you are using. cross check the package

Comment: @DEBENDRADHINDA org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional in both the Repo and Test

Comment: Adding `@Transactional` will make everything in the test method run in a single transaction. Whereas without  it you have 3 transactions. The fact is that your second `findByAID` returns the already retrieved object and doesn't query the DB again. This is simply how JPA works (it will retrieve it from the first level cache, the `EntityManager` itself). To fix, inject the `EntityManager` into your test, before querying do a `EntityManager.clear()` to clear the first level cache, so a query is forced.